# A specific problem with altering the Mac command-key layout to behave like Windows

Tags: keyboard, switching, internationalization, text-input

I want to change <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> combination to change keyboard layout to a Windows like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> but the Lion's keyboard settings does not react when I assign that particular combination. It allows me to change it to a other combinations, however. I assume this is because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is already being used by some other program, but which one? How can I tell that and what can I do to override that setting?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use alt + shift for anything by itself.  It is used for all kinds of special characters in combination with a letter key.

**How Mac OS X lets you toggle between different international language keyboard layouts**

[image]

**How Mac OS X uses the "Option" key as a "dead key" to enable typing diacriticals for Western European languages in the US keyboard layout.**

[image]

**Here is where a conflict may arise.**

[image]

Comment: The Alt-key, or Option key as we call it, on the Mac, is used in conjunction with letter keys to make letters with diacriticals, such as é, ü, ø, ñ and ç. Therefore I suspect it is not normally possible to remap this key. Sounds like a job for Ukelele, if it is possible at all. http://goo.gl/iFLae

Comment: Thanks! So is it correct to assume that this Command + Space combination has been used for that purpose for a long time?

Comment: The Option key has been used to type diacriticals since the first Mac in 1984.

Comment: Command-Space and Option-Command-Space are the reserved key combinations to advance from one keyboard layout to the next. I'll add a screen shot or two above.